# Unable to Setup Adwods API through Java, Giving several errors in last step

Tags: google-ads-api

I am Trying to set up Adwords API through Java, All the steps are going good but in last step while running GetCampaigns.java , Its giving several errors

> "Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.ads.common.lib.exception.OAuthException: Credential could not be refreshed.     at com.google.api.ads.common.lib.auth.OfflineCredentials.generateCredential(OfflineCredentials.java:240)    at adwords.axis.v201705.basicoperations.GetCampaigns.main(GetCampaigns.java:46) Caused by: com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request {   "error" : "invalid_grant" }    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)   at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.executeRefreshToken(Credential.java:570)    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:362)     at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)   at com.google.api.ads.common.lib.auth.OAuth2Helper.callRefreshToken(OAuth2Helper.java:69)   at com.google.api.ads.common.lib.auth.OfflineCredentials.generateCredential(OfflineCredentials.java:234)    ... 1 more"

After this error message its not going through.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a problem with your refresh token. Have you generated your refresh token?

I normally run this file to generate a refresh token.

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords_axis/src/main/java/adwords/axis/auth/GetRefreshToken.java

Did you copy the refresh token into your ads.properties file?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, Yes, i have generated refresh token. Yes i copied refresh token into ads.properties but before running this error comes. If you can help me please let me know.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late reply. Add the following line to your GetCampaign.java     System.out.println(oAuth2Credential.getRefreshToken()); 
 Where oAuth2Credential is an object of type Credential. Check if the refresh token matches the refresh token within your ad.properties file. If they do and you are still having problems let me know and I will create a test class for you to examine this further. Thanks

Comment: Hi Irfan, Thanks for your reply! Can you please let me know where i should add this line in GetCampaign.java , In which line because when i am adding this line it started giving syntax error. Please reply me as soon as possible.

Comment: If using this example code: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords_axis/src/main/java/adwords/axis/v201710/basicoperations/GetCampaigns.java add the following line to line 58:  System.out.println("Your refresh token is: "+oAuth2Credential.getRefreshToken());